# Pushout of schemes along submersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a field and $f : X \rightarrow B$ and $g : X \rightarrow C$ two smooth surjective morphisms with connected fibres. I am wondering if the pushout of the diagram
$$
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
X & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\
\downarrow{g} \\
C \\
\end{array}
$$

exist. Intuitively, given two fibrations, I am looking to construct the largest possible common base.

There are plenty of references in the case where $f$ and $g$ are closed immersions. This question [Pushout schemes/stacks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137527/pushout-schemes-stacks) is the closest I could get to, however, the counterexamples provided involve a finite morphism.

Comment: Confer Section 4 of Chapter IV of "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" by J'anos Koll'ar.